# Merge 2 dataframe based on if-else condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. a DF1 like this

```
DF1:

index    posts                                             type
-----------------------------------------------------------
0   know intj tool use interaction people excuse a...   INTJ
1   rap music ehh opp yeah know valid well know fa...   INTJ
2   preferably p hd low except wew lad video p min...   INTJ
3   drink like wish could drink red wine give head...   INTJ
4   space program ah bad deal meing freelance max ...   INTJ
...     ...     ...
106062  stay frustrate world life want take long nap w...   INFP
```

and a DF2 like this:

```
DF2:
 index  word    emotion     value
--------------------------------
0   aback   anger   0
1   aback   anticipation    0
2   aback   disgust     0
3   aback   fear    0
4   aback   joy     0
... ...    ...      ..
141535  zoom    negative    0
141536  zoom    positive    0
141537  zoom    sadness     1
```

**Expected result:**
a new dataframe with 3 columns

- *type*: the type from DF1.type
- *emotions*: a list of emotions from DF2.*emotion* if DF2.*word* is contained in DF1.*posts_tok* for entry *n* otherwise 'O'
- *posts_tok*: the splitted DF1.posts

```
    type emotions    posts_tok
-------------------------------------                                        
0   INTJ [joy,fear] [know, intj, tool, use, interaction, people, e...
1   INTJ  O         [rap, music, ehh, opp, yeah, know, valid, well...
2   INTJ [sadness]  [preferably, p, hd, low, except, wew, lad, vid...
3   INTJ  O         [drink, like, wish, could, drink, red, wine, g...
4   INTJ  O         [space, program, ah, bad, deal, meing, freelan...
...     ...     ...     ...
106062 INFP [disgust, anger, fear] [stay, frustrate, world, life, want, take, lon...
```

**My attempt:**

```
common_set=[]
common_emo=[]
#iter over each row in DF1
for key ,valuepost in DF1.iterrows():
    
    #split the value in the current row
    listvalues=valuepost['posts'].split()
    #iter over the list of the splitted value
    for listvalue in listvalues:
        #iter over each emotion in DF2.emotion
        for _, valueemo in DF2.emotion.items():
        # if emotion word matches with an element of the list of listvalue, append it else append a default value
            if valueemo == listvalue:
                common_emo.append(valueemo)
            else:
                common_emo.append('O')
    common_set.append({'posts_w':listvalue,'emovalue':common_emo,'type':valuepost['type']})

perso_emo_df=pd.DataFrame(common_set)
```

**Obtained Result:**

- Fail because of Out of Memory

**Request**

Can you please suggest an optimized way to get the same result?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post minimal reproducible example

Comment: Never include your data as pictures. Put it as a **text**.
We have neither time not desire to rewrite the content from your pictures to have source data to run tests. And limit your data to a reasonable volume (max. several dozens of rows). Definitely not over 100 K as in your picture.

Comment: Your first row ot the expected result contains "[joy,fear]".
So I assume that the post with index *0* contains "aback".
Now explain why this row should contain only "joy" and "fear", without other emotions included in DF2 for word == 'aback' (e.g. "anger").
And another remark: Put **whole** content of a row, without terminating "...", maybe shortened version of your original data, but including words leading to the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I defined both source DataFrames as:

```
                                               posts  type
0  know intj tool interaction people joy fear excuse  INTJ
1            rap music opp yeah know valid well know  INTJ
2            preferably sadness except wew lad video  INTJ
3               drink like wish could drink red wine  INTJ
4          space program ah bad deal meing freelance  INTJ
5       stay frustrate world take disgust anger fear  INFP
```

and

```
   token       emotion  value
0  aback         anger      1
1  aback  anticipation      2
2  aback       disgust      3
3  aback          fear      4
4  aback           joy      5
5   zoom      negative     11
6   zoom      positive     12
7   zoom       sadness     13
```

The first step is to create one additional column (*Word*), containing *posts*

Column converted to a list of words:

```
DF1['Word'] = DF1.posts.str.split()
```

and overwrite *posts* column with the same content:

```
DF1['posts'] = DF1.posts.str.split()
```

The reason to have just the same content in 2 columns is that one of them will be soon exploded, while the other should remain as is, for further processing.

The next step is to create a "working copy" of *DF2*, with *emotion* column as the index, but renamed to *Word*:

```
wrk2 = DF2.set_index('emotion')
wrk2.index.name = 'Word'
```

The result is:

```
              token  value
Word                      
anger         aback      1
anticipation  aback      2
disgust       aback      3
fear          aback      4
joy           aback      5
negative       zoom     11
positive       zoom     12
sadness        zoom     13
```

Then "explode" *DF1* on *Word* column, join it with *wrk2* and save the result as *wrk1* (another temporary DataFrame):

```
wrk1 = DF1.explode(column='Word').join(wrk2, on='Word')
```

It will be soon grouped and each group will be processed by the following function:

```
def proc(grp):
    emo = grp.dropna().Word
    row = grp.iloc[0]
    return pd.Series([row.type, emo.tolist() if emo.size > 0 else 'O', row.posts],
        index=['type', 'emotions', 'posts_tok'])
```

And to get the expected result, run:

```
result = wrk1.groupby(level=0).apply(proc)
```

The result, for my source data, is:

```
   type                emotions                                          posts_tok
0  INTJ             [joy, fear]  [know, intj, tool, interaction, people, joy, f... 
1  INTJ                       O   [rap, music, opp, yeah, know, valid, well, know] 
2  INTJ               [sadness]     [preferably, sadness, except, wew, lad, video] 
3  INTJ                       O       [drink, like, wish, could, drink, red, wine] 
4  INTJ                       O  [space, program, ah, bad, deal, meing, freelance] 
5  INFP  [disgust, anger, fear]  [stay, frustrate, world, take, disgust, anger,...
```

**Edit**: the problem with my initial solution is that the number of rows in the result of join is *size of DF1* times *size of DF1* times (roughly) the average number of words in *posts*.

So I came up with another solution - to apply a function to each row.

Start with a conversion of *posts* column from a single string to a list:

```
DF1.posts = DF1.posts.str.split()
```

Then define a set of *emotions* from *DF2*:

```
emos = set(DF2.emotion)
```

Then define a function, which will be applied to each row:

```
def rowProc(row, emos, defVal):
    matched = list(set(row.posts) & emos)
    return pd.Series([row.type, matched if len(matched) > 0 else defVal,
        row.posts],  index=['type', 'emotions', 'posts_tok'])
```

And to get the result, run:

```
result = DF1.apply(rowProc, axis=1, args=(emos, 'O'))
```

Comment: @valdi-bo thanks a lot for your solution, I really appreciate your help but I still encounter the Out oF Memory problem when I run this line
`wrk1 = DF1.explode(column='Word').join(wrk2, on='Word')` on Kaggle that has 16g.
This line works on my local machine but hangs at this `result = wrk1.groupby(level=0).apply(proc)` because is still memory-greedy (goes up to 60Gb) 
Is there any other optimized way? thanks

Comment: @valdi-bo...thanks! It works fast!... but I have a problem with the results. In fact `emos = set(DF2.emotion)` should be `words = set(DF2.words)` and then this `matched = list(set(row.posts) & emos)` should be `matched = list(set(row.posts) & words)` and then this line `matched if len(matched) > 0 else defVal`should get the corresponding  value in the column `DF2.emotions ` for each `matched`... How to make sure that this line is modified to do this?  Many thanks

Comment: I'm afraid, your concept is either ambiguous or at least unclear.
Assume that some post contains word "aback".
Then it is unclear, which emotion should be taken for further processing (you have five of them).
It is better when you post another question, with detailed explanation,
**complete** source data and the expected result.

Comment: You are right. I tried to be more accurate. If you look at DF2 (the dataframe with emotions) you can see that ‘value’ is sometime 1 (the emotion is predicated for that word) and sometime 0 (the emotion is NOT predicated for that word). Let’s take the example of “aback” since alla values are set to 0 and if you encounter “aback” in DF1.posts, then the output will be O. If we take the example of “zoom” the final output should be ‘[sadness]’  but not ‘negative’ or ’positive’. I hope to have clarified better the point.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Still unclear why the first row of your expected result should contain *joy* and *fear*.
*Emotion* for both these rows is *0*, so they should not appeat in the result.
Provide **full** source data (of reasonable size) and the expected result.